# Rails Find based on a set existing in through a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to select an instance based on a relation of that instance containing a set.  A simplified example follows:

```
class Product::Variation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :product_id, :quantity

  belongs_to :product
  has_many :bids, :foreign_key => :product_variation_id
  has_many :product_variation_property_values, :class_name => 'Product::Variation::PropertyValue'
  has_many :property_values, :through => :product_variation_property_values, :class_name => 'Property::Value'
end

class Product::Variation::PropertyValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :property_value_id, :variation_id, :property_id

  belongs_to :variation
  belongs_to :property_value, :class_name => 'Property::Value'
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :values, :class_name => 'Property::Value'
end

class Property::Value < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :partner
end
```

So now I want to do something like the following (in psuedo code):

```
Variation.where(:property_values includes [Property::Value.find(1), Property::Value.find(2)])
```

Is there a way to do this using ActiveRecord?

Thanks and let me know if you need more info.

***More Info***

I tried the following:

```
Product::Variation.joins(:property_values).where('property_values.id' => [Property::Value.find(1).id, Property::Value.find(2).id]).first
```

...which is the following SQL...

```
SELECT "product_variations".* FROM "product_variations" INNER JOIN "product_variation_property_values" ON "product_variation_property_values"."variation_id" = "product_variations"."id" INNER JOIN "property_values" ON "property_values"."id" = "product_variation_property_values"."property_value_id" WHERE "property_values"."id" IN (1, 2)
```

...and this returns...

```
#<Product::Variation id: 25, product_id: 1, quantity: 39, created_at: "2013-11-18 00:18:45", updated_at: "2013-11-18 00:18:45">
```

But if I do:

```
Product::Variation.find(25).property_values.inspect
```

...I get...

```
[#<Property::Value id: 1, property_id: 1, content: "XS", created_at: "2013-11-18 00:18:45", updated_at: "2013-11-18 00:18:45", color: nil, color_texture: nil, secondary_color: nil>, #<Property::Value id: 6, property_id: 2, content: "Dark Wood", created_at: "2013-11-18 00:18:45", updated_at: "2013-11-18 00:18:45", color: "#855E42", color_texture: "striped", secondary_color: "#FFB90F">]
```

But I'm looking for the `Product::Variation` that contains both `Property::Value` 1 and 2.  This is returning those that contain 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable with a `join` query. Hard to write form heart, but should be something like this:

```
Variation.joins(propert_values: :values).where('values.id' => [Property::Value.find(1).id, Property::Value.find(2).id]).first
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested with a few edits, but see my results under ***More Info*** above.